# Error with SEO Lite Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in

Tags: seo-lite

Runnng EE version 2.11 and SEO Lite 1.3.5 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in /xxxxx/expressionengine/third_party/seo_lite/mcp.seo_lite.php on line 97

This occurs when accessing the default module page to input the default data for SEO Lite. 
Line 97 is the one in the middle 
$vars['_form_base'] = $this->form_base;
        $this->EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', lang($lang_key));
        $this->EE->cp->set_breadcrumb($this->base, lang('seo_lite_module_name'));

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the line

```
$this->EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', lang($lang_key));
```

to

```
$this->EE->view->cp_page_title = lang($lang_key);
```

Comment: you're most welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the latest version of SEO Lite here: https://github.com/bjornbjorn/SEO-Lite